# Unity/Android - Which OAuth credentials for enabling Game Services?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-oauth, google-play-console, google-play-games

I've built and released an Android app developed in Unity

**Expectation:**

- Play Services popup to appear on opening the app
- Achievements button to open the achievements page

**Current Result:**

(When downloading the released version, internal test version, internally shared version)

- No popup when downloading my current released version
- *'[Play Games Plugin ... Returning an error code'* - in the Android logcat
- Pressing achievement button says that GPGS isn't initialised

**Past result (somehow, before I broke it):**
(In the released version + internal test versions)

- Players would get the popup on opening the app
- Achievement button would open the achievements page

**My Theory:**
Some searching online reveals this is a SHA1 certificate issue...

**My Build + Signing + OAuth Process:**

On the *Google Play Console > Setup and Management > App Integrity*, there are two key fingerprints:

- *Upload key certificate* (Fingerprint A)
- *App Signing key Certificate* (Fingerprint B)

When I build my app, I sign it with the *Upload key certificate* (*fingerprint A*) as a bundle. Google then signs it automatically with their automatic *App Signing key Certificate*(*fingerprint B*), as far as I understand it.

In my *Credentials* section, I currently have two credentials, each  one with a different OAuth client assigned to it:

- *Credential 1 - Android Client using fingerprint A + '*Use for new installs: false*'*
- *Credential 2 - Android Client using fingerprint B + '*Use for new installs: true*'*

All these changes have been published in the publish section.

In the *OAuth Consent Screen* section, the app is set to *TESTING* and has never been published. I've read conflicting documentation on whether this is relevant if I just want achievements. I have so far assumed that it isn't necessary, because it has previously worked fine in the released version.

**Questions:**

- Which credential is the one that would give the expected results in the *Production* version?
- Which credential should have 'use for new installs' checked?
- Is the OAuth consent screen relevant to me if I simply want
  achievements? And if it is relevant, why has this setup previously
  worked?

I've spent a week being completely dumbfounded by this entire process, thanks to anyone who can offer some clarity.